# Create cycle plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am looking to create a cycle plot of hours within months. I am hoping it will look something like the plot bellow. I am aiming for the plot to indicate mean temperature for each month with a horizontal line, and then within each month have the graph show the temperature fluctuations across the typical day of that month. I was trying to use `monthplot()` but it doesn't seem to be working:

[image]

```
library(nycflights13)

tempdata <- weather %>% group_by(hour) 

monthplot(tempdata, labels = NULL, ylab = "temp")
```

It keeps saying `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA` but I am not sure where the code is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Hope that this `ggplot2` solution will work:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Prepare data
tempdata <- weather %>% 
    group_by(month, day) %>%
    summarise(temp = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE))
meanMonth <- tempdata %>%
    group_by(month) %>%
    summarise(temp = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE))

# Plot using ggplot2
ggplot(tempdata, aes(day, temp)) +
    geom_hline(data = meanMonth, aes(yintercept = temp)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(~ month, switch = "x") +
    labs(x = "Month",
         y = "Temperature") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: @njw3498 can you please accept solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

`temp` has a missing value which causes an error. You also need to set the `times` and `phase` arguments.

```
library(nycflights13)

# Find mean value : this automatically removes the observation with missing data that was causing an error
tempdata <- aggregate(temp ~ month + day, data=weather, mean) 

with(tempdata, monthplot(temp, times=day , phase=month, ylab = "temp"))
```

[image]